# How to remove .ncrunchproject files (or any other files that are similar) from .Net Core project/solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, ncrunch

I have added `NCrunch` to my .Net Core solution and now this file was added to all projects:

```
ProjectName.v3.ncrunchproject
```

I have added this to gitignore so it's not going to source control, but how can I remove it from Project?

There is an option of excluding this file explicitly in each and every project by either clicking Exclude in menu or adding it manually in .csproj file. I hope though that a better solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to modify `DefaultItemExcludes` in sdk project props. For example go to:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\<version>\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem\build\netstandard1.0`

and modify `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props`.

Find something like:

```
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\node_modules\**;node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
```

and change it to:

```
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**\node_modules\**;node_modules\**;**\*.ncrunchproject</DefaultItemExcludes>
```

After Visual Studio restart it should be automatically excluded from your project. This is not a perfect solution, because you will have to do it for every project type and sdk you have.

Comment: This will also have to be done on each developers machine, it's quite sad there is no better solution to this